# Wall outlet cable seems to have suddenly lost power

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, gfci

I'm so confused. I have an outlet in my basement, whose power cable I can trace directly to my fuse box. There are no other outlets on this cable. It was working fine but I needed GFCI outlets, so I installed them - and nothing happened. Pressed reset on the GFCIs, no lights, nothing. So I reinstalled the old outlet (I don't have a voltage tester) and that's not working either.

It appears as if the cable itself has somehow lost power. The breaker does not appear to be a GFCI breaker (no reset button, just a switch) and I'm sure it's on when I test.

There is another outlet on the same breaker that still works fine when the breaker is on.

What could be happening here??

*Edit*

Also, I should have mentioned - these outlets are part of a double breaker, which is how there are outlets on a different line that were still running otherwise.

Comment: Easiest is a broken wire in the cable or a wire not connected.   A multi-meter can usually find where the power is.  You are using the screws to connect the wire to outlet, not the back stabs?  Check the connections at the other outlet, it should be between the panel and non working outlet since it has power.

Comment: If cable is inside a wall, might also find a dead mouse.

Comment: @crip659  Yep, been there, done that. My experience was that when the mice chewed thru the cable, they got electrocuted and the breaker actually tripped.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson  Think it was your picture a few months ago that gave me the idea.

Comment: _I'm_ confused! You say that there are no other outlets on the cable and that the outlet is dead, yet there is another outlet on the same breaker that works OK. _Please_ [edit] your question to include pictures of exactly how you've wired the non-functioning outlet, the breaker itself (preferably with the panel cover off), and the wiring on the currently working outlet. Be sure to turn power off at the breaker before pulling outlets to get pics of wiring.

Comment: @freeman there can be a junction and at that point it goes directly back to the panel , a photo of the wiring at the receptacle will probably show   a pigtail that the wire to this receptacle either hot or neutral could be loose at the wire nut.

Comment: Delete your recent edit and type it up as an answer,  you answered your own question which is allowed.

Comment: @Guillaume why are you using another login name to update your post?

Comment: Please [merge](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) your two accounts so that you can interact with posts properly.  Also, post your edit as an answer and I'll give you a +1 for it

Comment: @JACK done & made Community Wiki. Give it a vote. ;)

Answer (score 4):

*Answered by OP in an edit to the question:*

Thanks for the responses! My apologies for the confusion.

I went back to double check my observations, and noticed that where I had thought the cable was just going behind some insulation for a few inches in the basement, it actually goes up to an outdoor outlet whose GFCI was tripped! I reset that outdoor outlet and the others are now functioning.

Comment: Typically a GFCI outlet is installed with additional outlets connected such that they are protected by the first receptacle, i.e. _tailed off_ the GFCI device, and that is indicated by a label applied to each of the additional outlets. Having an outlet protected by a series of GFCI devices is frowned upon. Did you reinstall the original outlet which was protected by the upstream GFCI?